# Remove single quote from just end of array element (String) in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have array of 3000 elements which are like this

```
   Array[0]= 405adc92-cfad-4be6-9ad2-ca363eda4933
   Array[1]= 405adc92-cfad-4be6-9ad2-ca363eda4933
```

And I need to pass a variable in a function which require only a single quote at the beginning. I tried a solution on web which is pasting single quote on beginning and end aswell .like this

```
function add_quotes($str) {
   return sprintf("'%s'", $str);
}
$csv =  implode(',', array_map('add_quotes', $a));
 $myArray = explode(',', $csv);
echo gettype($myArray[1]);
```

so answer is like this

```
myArray[1]='405adc92-cfad-4be6-9ad2-ca363eda4933'
```

So what Could I do to get rid ?

Comment: this could be the droid you are looking for http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I am new in php, I tried to use trim but can't get output. can you make a small example please ?

Comment: sure thing bud :)

Comment: @ephemeral Why not putting only one quote in add_quotes function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

could you not just add the ' at the beginning of each string, rather than first add too many of them and afterwards remove the wrongly placed?

```
foreach($myArray as $key => &$value) {
  $value = "'" . $value;
}
```

or (may be more readable as not by-reference)

```
foreach($myArray as $key => $value) {
  $myArray[$key] = "'" . $value;
}
```

Comment: I do not understand either why to create a problem and then try to solve it if you can do it right way from the beginning.

Comment: @GinoPane actually I was fixing other developer bug

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rtrim` - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php to achieve. The generic syntax is:

```
<?php
    $foo = 'my string\'';
    $bar = rtrim($foo, '\'');

    var_dump($foo); //shows my string'
    var_dump($bar); //shows my string
```

so in your case take the array values, then use `rtrim($myArray['myKey'], '\'')` - this should do it for you :)

Comment: Didnt work, I think I is to remove ',' comma  not quote.

Comment: @ephemeral I used comma in my rtrim example - do you mean you wish to get rid of quotes?

Comment: Only last one .   out should  like     **'123213231313**  in start there is comma but not on end.

Comment: there is no comma in that string - `,` is a comma, `'` is a quote?

Comment: no there is not . just quote at the end and beginning . And yes its quote single quote